# How to find unmatched brackets in a text file?

Tags: text-processing

Today I learned that I can use `perl -c filename` to find unmatched curly brackets {} in arbitrary files, not necessarily Perl scripts. The problem is, it doesn't work with other types of brackets () [] and maybe <>. I also had experiments with several Vim plugins that claims to help finding unmatched brackets but so far not so good.

I have a text file with quite a few brackets and one of them is missing! Is there any program / script / vim plugin / whatever that can help me identify the unmatched bracket?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Vim you can use <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> to quickly travel to nearest unmatched bracket of the type entered in the next keystroke.

So <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> will take you back up to the nearest unmatched "{"; <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>)</kbd> would take you ahead to the nearest unmatched ")", and so on.

Comment: I will also add that in vim you can use % (Shift 5, in the USA) to immediately find the _matching_ bracket for the one you're on.

Comment: Onfortunately, this does not work for brackets. `[[` and `]]` actually go to the next open/closed *brace* in the first column respectively.

Answer (score 8):

**Update 2:**
The following script now prints out the line number and column of a mismached *bracket*. It processes one bracket type per scan (ie. '[]' '<>' '{}' '()' ...)
The script identifies the **first** ,*unmatched right bracket*, or the first of any *un-paired left bracket*... On detecting an erroe, it exits with the line and column numbers

Here is some sample output...

---

```
File = /tmp/fred/test/test.in
Pair = ()

*INFO:  Group 1 contains 1 matching pairs

ERROR: *END-OF-FILE* encountered after Bracket 7.
        A Left "(" is un-paired in Group 2.
        Group 2 has 1 un-paired Left "(".
        Group 2 begins at Bracket 3.
  see:  Line, Column (8, 10)
        ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7
000008  (   )    (         (         (     )   )
```

Here is the script...

---

```
#!/bin/bash

# Itentify the script
bname="$(basename "$0")"
# Make a work dir
wdir="/tmp/$USER/$bname"
[[ ! -d "$wdir" ]] && mkdir -p "$wdir"

# Arg1: The bracket pair 'string'
pair="$1"
# pair='[]' # test
# pair='<>' # test
# pair='{}' # test
# pair='()' # test

# Arg2: The input file to test
ifile="$2"
  # Build a test source file
  ifile="$wdir/$bname.in"
  cp /dev/null "$ifile"
  while IFS= read -r line ;do
    echo "$line" >> "$ifile"
  done <<EOF
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
[   ]    [         [         [
<   >    <         
                   <         >         
                             <    >    >         >
----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6
{   }    {         }         }         }         } 
(   )    (         (         (     )   )                    
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
EOF

echo "File = $ifile"
# Count how many: Left, Right, and Both
left=${pair:0:1}
rght=${pair:1:1}
echo "Pair = $left$rght"
# Make a stripped-down 'skeleton' of the source file - brackets only
skel="/tmp/$USER/$bname.skel" 
cp /dev/null "$skel"
# Make a String Of Brackets file ... (It is tricky manipulating bash strings with []..
sed 's/[^'${rght}${left}']//g' "$ifile" > "$skel"
< "$skel" tr  -d '\n'  > "$skel.str"
Left=($(<"$skel.str" tr -d "$left" |wc -m -l)); LeftCt=$((${Left[1]}-${Left[0]}))
Rght=($(<"$skel.str" tr -d "$rght" |wc -m -l)); RghtCt=$((${Rght[1]}-${Rght[0]}))
yBkts=($(sed -e "s/\(.\)/ \1 /g" "$skel.str"))
BothCt=$((LeftCt+RghtCt))
eleCtB=${#yBkts[@]}
echo

if (( eleCtB != BothCt )) ; then
  echo "ERROR:  array Item Count ($eleCtB)"
  echo "     should equal BothCt ($BothCt)"
  exit 1
else
  grpIx=0            # Keep track of Groups of nested pairs
  eleIxFir[$grpIx]=0 # Ix of First Bracket in a specific Group
  eleCtL=0           # Count of Left brackets in current Group 
  eleCtR=0           # Count of Right brackets in current Group
  errIx=-1           # Ix of an element in error.
  for (( eleIx=0; eleIx < eleCtB; eleIx++ )) ; do
    if [[ "${yBkts[eleIx]}" == "$left" ]] ; then
      # Left brackets are 'okay' until proven otherwise
      ((eleCtL++)) # increment Left bracket count
    else
      ((eleCtR++)) # increment Right bracket count
      # Right brackets are 'okay' until their count exceeds that of Left brackets
      if (( eleCtR > eleCtL )) ; then
        echo
        echo "ERROR:  MIS-matching Right \"$rght\" in Group $((grpIx+1)) (at Bracket $((eleIx+1)) overall)"
        errType=$rght    
        errIx=$eleIx    
        break
      elif (( eleCtL == eleCtR )) ; then
        echo "*INFO:  Group $((grpIx+1)) contains $eleCtL matching pairs"
        # Reset the element counts, and note the first element Ix for the next group
        eleCtL=0
        eleCtR=0
        ((grpIx++))
        eleIxFir[$grpIx]=$((eleIx+1))
      fi
    fi
  done
  #
  if (( eleCtL > eleCtR )) ; then
    # Left brackets are always potentially valid (until EOF)...
    # so, this 'error' is the last element in array
    echo
    echo "ERROR: *END-OF-FILE* encountered after Bracket $eleCtB."
    echo "        A Left \"$left\" is un-paired in Group $((grpIx+1))."
    errType=$left
    unpairedCt=$((eleCtL-eleCtR))
    errIx=$((${eleIxFir[grpIx]}+unpairedCt-1))
    echo "        Group $((grpIx+1)) has $unpairedCt un-paired Left \"$left\"."
    echo "        Group $((grpIx+1)) begins at Bracket $((eleIxFir[grpIx]+1))."
  fi

  # On error, get Line and Column numbers
  if (( errIx >= 0 )) ; then
    errLNum=0    # Source Line number (current).
    eleCtSoFar=0 # Count of bracket-elements in lines processed so far.
    errItemNum=$((errIx+1)) # error Ix + 1 (ie. "1 based")
    # Read the skeketon file to find the error line-number
    while IFS= read -r skline ; do
      ((errLNum++))
      brackets="${skline//[^"${rght}${left}"]/}" # remove whitespace
      ((eleCtSoFar+=${#brackets}))
      if (( eleCtSoFar >= errItemNum )) ; then
        # We now have the error line-number
        # ..now get the relevant Source Line 
        excerpt=$(< "$ifile" tail -n +$errLNum |head -n 1)
        # Homogenize the brackets (to be all "Left"), for easy counting
        mogX="${excerpt//$rght/$left}"; mogXCt=${#mogX} # How many 'Both' brackets on the error line? 
        if [[ "$errType" == "$left" ]] ; then
          # R-Trunc from the error element [inclusive]
          ((eleTruncCt=eleCtSoFar-errItemNum+1))
          for (( ele=0; ele<eleTruncCt; ele++ )) ; do
            mogX="${mogX%"$left"*}"   # R-Trunc (Lazy)
          done
          errCNum=$((${#mogX}+1))
        else
          # errType=$rght
          mogX="${mogX%"$left"*}"   # R-Trunc (Lazy)
          errCNum=$((${#mogX}+1))
        fi
        echo "  see:  Line, Column ($errLNum, $errCNum)"
        echo "        ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7"  
        printf "%06d  $excerpt\n\n" $errLNum
        break
      fi
    done < "$skel"
  else
    echo "*INFO:  OK. All brackets are paired."
  fi
fi
exit
```

Comment: This is awesome, but it seems to always print `Line, Column (8, 10)` no matter which file I try it on. Also `mogXCt=${#mogX}` is set but not used anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

The best option is vim/gvim as identified by Shadur, but if you want a script, you can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667494/awk-brackets-checking/4420435#4420435) to a similar question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). I repeat my whole answer here:

If what you are trying to do applies to a general purpose language, then this is a non-trivial problem.

To start with you will have to worry about comments and strings. If you want to check this on a programming language that uses regular expressions, this will make your quest harder again.

So before I can come in and give you any advice on your question I need to know the limits of your problem area. If you can guarantee that there are no strings, no comments and no regular expressions to worry about - or more generically nowhere in the code that brackets can possibly be used other than for the uses for which you are checking that they are balanced - this will make life a lot simpler.

Knowing the language that you want to check would be helpful.

---

If I take the hypothesis that there is no noise, i.e. that all brackets are useful brackets, my strategy would be iterative:

I would simply look for and remove all inner bracket pairs: those that contain no brackets inside. This is best done by collapsing all lines to a single long line (and find a mechanism to to add line references, should you need to get that information out). In this case the search and replace is pretty simple:

It requires an array:

```
B["("]=")"; B["["]="]"; B["{"]="}"
```

And a loop through those elements:

```
for (b in B) {gsub("[" b "][^][(){}]*[" B[b] "]", "", $0)}
```

My test file is as follows:

```
#!/bin/awk

($1 == "PID") {
  fo (i=1; i<NF; i++)
  {
    F[$i] = i
  }
}

($1 + 0) > 0 {
  count("VIRT")
  count("RES")
  count("SHR")
  count("%MEM")
}

END {
  pintf "VIRT=\t%12d\nRES=\t%12d\nSHR=\t%12d\n%%MEM=\t%5.1f%%\n", C["VIRT"], C["RES"], C["SHR"], C["%MEM"]
}

function count(c[)
{
  f=F[c];

  if ($f ~ /m$/)
  {
    $f = ($f+0) * 1024
  }

  C[c]+=($f+0)
}
```

My full script (without line referencing) is as follows:

```
cat test-file-for-brackets.txt | \
  tr -d '\r\n' | \
  awk \
  '
    BEGIN {
      B["("]=")";
      B["["]="]";
      B["{"]="}"
    }
    {
      m=1;
      while(m>0)
      {
        m=0;
        for (b in B)
        {
          m+=gsub("[" b "][^][(){}]*[" B[b] "]", "", $0)
        }
      };
      print
    }
  '
```

The output of that script stops on the innermost illegal uses of brackets.
But beware: 1/ this script will not work with brackets in comments, regular expressions or strings, 2/ it does not report where in the original file the problem is located, 3/ although it will remove all balanced pairs it stops at the innermost error conditions and keeps all englobbing brackets.

Point 3/ is probably an exploitable result, though I'm not sure of the reporting mechanism you had in mind.

Point 2/ is relatively easy to implement but takes more than a few minutes work to produce, so I'll leave it up to you to figure out.

Point 1/ is the tricky one because you enter a whole new realm of competing sometimes nested beginnings and endings, or special quoting rules for special characters...